# How to create visibility/sight effects in 3D

Tags: 3d

In a typical 2D game with a top-down perspective or similar, it is common to create some sort of shadow-like visibility effect. This is demonstrated here: https://ncase.me/sight-and-light/ . The effect is useful in the game play to hide certain parts of the world/level to the player. It can also easily be used for multiple "agents", so that the player only sees what his/hers agents sees.

I have a hard time figuring out how this would look in 3D, to give a similar effect. To simplify, let's assume that the game has more or less a top-down camera view or a camera view that is common in most management type games.

- Should you still draw the objects outside the field? Should it just be black?
- Are there examples of how other 3D games does this?

Comment: Just an idea:
Make the walls extrude into infinity towards the height axis and paint them black.

Comment: "Should you still draw the objects outside the field? Should it just be black?" - this sounds like a question of art direction and visual style. Can you show us a screenshot or target visual mock-up of your game, so we can get a sense of what it looks like, what kinds of objects you're dealing with, and the kind of aesthetic you're going for?